# Computing the Expectation of the Square of a Random Variable: $ \text{E}[X^{2}] $.

Tags: probability, random-variables

What is the rule for computing $ \text{E}[X^{2}] $, where $ \text{E} $ is the expectation operator and $ X $ is a random variable?

Let $ S $ be a sample space, and let $ p(x) $ denote the probability mass function of $ X $.

Is
$$
\text{E}[X^{2}] = \sum_{x \in S} x^{2} \cdot p(x),
$$
or do I also need to square the $ x $ appearing in $ p(x) $?

Comment: Yes, that's it (as long as $X$ is discrete).

Comment: Yes, this is called second moment.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306425/expected-value-function/

Comment: Dear CodeKingPlusPlus, you have to be a little careful with the formula that you’ve written down. The variable $ x $ should only take values in the range of the random variable $ X $. Just because $ X $ is discrete doesn’t mean that the sample space $ \Omega $ is finite or countably infinite. :)

Comment: Apart from that, the formula is correct! There’s no need to square the $ x $ in the expression $ p(x) $.

Comment: See [Expectation of square of random variable and their mean.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487377/expectation-of-square-of-random-variable-and-their-mean)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In general, if $ (\Omega,\Sigma,P) $ is a probability space and $ X: (\Omega,\Sigma) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})) $ is a real-valued random variable, then
$$
\text{E}[X^{2}] = \int_{\Omega} X^{2} ~ d{P}.
$$
Although this formula works for all cases, it is rarely used, especially when $ X $ is known to have certain nice properties.

**Examples:**

- If $ X $ is a discrete random variable (i.e., its cumulative distribution function (cdf) is a step-function) and $ p $ is its probability mass function (pmf), then we can use the formula
  $$
  \text{E}[X^{2}] = \sum_{x \in \text{Range}(X)} x^{2} \cdot p(x).
  $$
- If $ X $ is an [absolutely continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) random variable (i.e., its cdf is an absolutely continuous function), then it possesses a probability density function (pdf) $ f $. We thus have the formula
  $$
  \text{E}[X^{2}] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x^{2} f(x) ~ d{\mu(x)},
  $$
  where $ \mu $ is the standard Borel measure on $ \mathbb{R} $. Of course, if $ f $ is continuous, then we can simply compute the improper Riemann integral
  $$
  \text{E}[X^{2}] = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} x^{2} f(x) ~ d{x}.
  $$

Comment: The random variable is defined as mapping b/w sample space and real number. What is the role of events($\Sigma$) in random variable ?

Comment: Events are subsets of the sample space.