# Expected value of squared random variable if expected value of random variable is $0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value

Let

$E[X]=0$

them How is Expected value of $E[X^2]$ ?  in my opinion is $0$ But I need confirmation and explanation

In general, if $ (\Omega,\Sigma,P) $ is a probability space and $ X: (\Omega,\Sigma) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})) $ is a real-valued random variable, then
$$
\text{E}[X^{2}] = \int_{\Omega} X^{2} ~ d{P}.
$$

see for more about this in this quetion [Computing the Expectation of the Square of a Random Variable: $E[X^2]$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306659/computing-the-expectation-of-the-square-of-a-random-variable-textex2/306694#306694)

Comment: If X is 1 half the time and -1 half the time, E(X) =0, bur X^2=1 all the time, so E(X^2)=1. Hope this example helps see whats going on

Answer (score 0):

No way. Since $X^2\geq 0$, $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=0$ iff $X$ is zero almost surely.

Otherwise, if $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ is well defined, $\mathbb{E}[X^2]\color{red}{>}0.$

Comment: So, if the expected value of x is zero What I can say about expected value of x squared?

Comment: You can't say anything about $E(X^2)=V(X)$. For example, suppose $X\sim N(0,a)$ where $a>0$ is fixed and arbitrary. Then $E(X)=0$ whereas $E(X^2)=a$.

Answer (score 0):

A really easy example to disabuse yourself of this notion is to look up standard [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) and [$\chi^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) distributions.

If $Z \sim N(0, 1)$, then $Z^2 \sim \chi_1^2$. We have $\mathrm E[Z] = 0$, but $\mathrm E[Z^2] = 1$.